# REPL / LINQpad / F# interactive alternative for C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, code-snippets, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

I love using LINQpad and FSI while developing code for C# and F#.  For haskell, I've used hugs.  And of course, scripting languages almost always come with a REPL.  Pretty much every modern browser ships with a fairly fancy javascript repl/ide.

Is there something similar for C++0x?

Neat features would be:

- can include/link to preexisting code
- compile cycle is short&fast - taking a second is OK, taking minutes is not.
- autocomplete/intellisense or similar would be nice, or at least a decent google-this-function-for-me keyshortcut
- at least partial C++0x support.

I mostly use windows, but if there's a great tool on linux that doesn't require 1337 hours to configure on each new distro (i.e. not most emacs configurations) I'd be interested in hearing of those too.

**Related:** [C++ interpreter / console / snippet compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189097/c-interpreter-console-snippet-compiler) (two years ago, linux-focused)

***Edit:*** A not entirely irrelevant note is that I'd like to use this to get a feel for C++0x amongst other things - so as much as possible C++0x support - at least for auto and lambdas - would be nice.  I'm not looking for a statement-by-statement repl so much as a rapid development environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the same place, try cling: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/category/package-context/cling
It's a fairly young project and it is the successor of cint.
It will support all the c++0x features which clang supports.

Comment: @user: cling != cint; but yeah, they're apparently by the same team.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

Comment: Hmm, looks like this doesn't support C++0x - but better than nothing, thanks!