# Is there an interactive interpreter for C#?

Tags: c#, shell

Sometimes it's handy to have access to your language to do quick things without starting Visual Studio and creating a new console app.

Is there something like Python's interactive mode or groovy shell, except for C#?

Comment: Duplicate/Similar Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537/c-console

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 includes a C# Interactive window.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**Update for 2022**

After installing Visual Studio 2022, add the following to your `PATH` environment variable.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.6.1\tools`

Then open your terminal (CMD, PowerShell, Windows Terminal) and type `csi` to run C Sharp Interactive.

You'll get something like this:

```
PS C:\> csi
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 2.6.1.62414
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Type "#help" for more information.
> var list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
> list // You don't need to call Console.WriteLine() to see values
List<int>(4) { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
> // You can keep adding lines as needed
```

---

**Previous Answer**

With the [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) there now is a C# Interactive tool window built into Visual Studio.

The new tool window is invoked by going to `View` → `Other Windows` → `C# Interactive`.

For Visual Studio 2010 to 2013 you can use the [Roslyn CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685) to get a similar tool window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Install from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn then 'view / other windows / c# interactive'

Comment: This is the most correct answer now.

Comment: And it is available in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. Link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx#Csharp

Comment: The command line version can be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csi.exe` (automatically in the PATH in the VS developer command prompt)

Answer (score 37):

Have a look at [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) (part of the Mono project). Never used it myself, I hasten to add.

For LINQ stuff, you should also look at [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: Indeed, LINQPad is useful for more than just LINQ!

Comment: LinqPad is a great piece of software but i find Snippet Compiler to be the lightest and quickest for testing snippets. Give it a try as well.

Comment: I always run a VS Console App project in the background.

Comment: CsharpRepl works quite well. Doesn't interpret files, but there was some development on it.

Comment: +1 for LINQPad, I hadn't used that before. I don't have mono installed here, I'll have to check out CsharpRepl later tonight.

Comment: CSharpRepl *works*, but it's a little rough around the edges.

Comment: It's worth noting that as nice as LINQPad is, it does not offer a "true" interactive environment like CsharpRepl does (that is, results are not persisted across executions).

Answer (score 10):

There are [several](http://www.google.com/search?q=csharp+interactive+shell).

- [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl)
- [CSI: A Simple C# Interpreter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csi.aspx)
- [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)
- [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx)

Comment: Well, and the first couple of results are all about the same one ...

Comment: Looking at the first couple of results is usually not a good idea, no matter the search engine.  You need to explore the first page or two, perhaps even three, if you are feeling ambitious.  This, in addition to trying different search terms really helps broaden your search.

Comment: CSI doesn't seem to support the latestfeatures of the language. I found a tip here: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2635407/Update-for-NET-Framework-3-5.aspx that was supposed to fix this, but I was unable to get that version working properly.

Answer (score 9):

Like others noted, Mono's CSharpRepl is probably the right answer. However, if you're not fixed to C#, then [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is a pretty nice environment of playing around with .NET. I frequently use it to test regular expressions, format strings, etc. All the kinds of stuff you have ConsoleProject163 lying around for :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other good answers here (+1), there is also [CSI](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2010/01/07/the-source-code-is-still-the-executable-updated-csi-a-c-interpreter-with-source-and-tests-for-net-4.aspx) and the [immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28VS.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio.

Comment: The immediate windows is nice, but you can't define classes on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Mono [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) which is what you are looking for.

> This documents the features available
>   in the C# interactive shell that is
>   part of Mono's C# compiler. An
>   interactive shell is usually referred
>   to as a read eval print loop or repl.
>   The C# interactive shell is built on
>   top of the Mono.CSharp
>   (http:/monodoc/N:Mono.CSharp) library,
>   a library that provides a C# compiler
>   service that can be used to evaluate
>   expressions and statements on-the-fly.

Answer (score 4):

There is [ScriptCS](http://scriptcs.net/) which uses the Roslyn CTP nuget package.

Comment: ScriptCs now has interactive shell too - http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/05/07/scriptcs-gets-a-repl/

Answer (score 3):

I think [CShell](http://cshell.net/) would be a nice contribution to answers given here.
It provides code completion enabled REPL command window as well as a lightweight workspace management tools to include some scratch files and library references.

Answer (score 2):

With Roslyn CTP there now is a full C# interactive window from Microsoft direct in Visual Studio!!
Works great! So far runs all my libraries. 
After install: Invoking View -> Other Windows -> C# Interactive from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ideone.com](https://ideone.com) sometimes, but [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) is a good choice if an install is acceptable.

Comment: +1 for reminding me of LINQPad, I have it installed but I rarely use it nowadays. It is not an interactive shell as such but amost. It is so quick to bash down one or more lines and see the output. It is great to get the syntax right with regular expressions for example. (LINQPad can be used for much more than that!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-02.html) developed by Miguel De Icaza, is shipped with mono and have code completion

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple web based environment to crank out some C# code try [coderpad.io](https://coderpad.io) Not sure if you can add libraries n' all but its a quick and simple solution if you are just interested in testing out several commands