# A REPL environment for C#

Tags: c#, shell, scripting

Is there a way to use C# interactively, inside a REPL environment like Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an interactive interpreter for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058715/is-there-an-interactive-interpreter-for-c)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at C# script: http://www.csscript.net/

Comment: Can I use it via the command-line interface like Python (this is what I meant by Interactively).

Answer (score 1):

If by interactively you mean not having to manually compile or run as a console application, then yes. There are several tools that allow this.

The best, imo, is LinqPad. See: http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1):

Mono offers some ways you can consider take a look at http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

Comment: Mono--its not just for linux devs.

Comment: There is not a Windows version as I know. Am I right?

Comment: @Wassim, I haven't tried it. But, .NET applications in general are not *not* Windows or any platform specific. Unless they p-invoke or use a library with platform only features.

Comment: Found this thread looking for the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058715/is-there-an-interactive-interpreter-for-c